# Basic parsing of XML string with XML::Twig

Tags: xml, perl, xml-twig

I've used XML::Simple for over a decade and it's done everything I need it to, and I barely ever touch Perl any more.  Though right now I need to parse an XML string to simply: get all of the elements that are children of the root, and for each get their element type, attributes, and content (I don't care if there is any nested elements, just reading the content as a string is perfect).  I can do all that with XML::Simple EXCEPT I also need to keep the order, which Simple can't do when there are multiple element types.

I just installed Twig and it looks very overwhelming for something I hoped would be a quick script. It's unlikely that I'll ever use Twig again after this, is this something that Twig can do easily?

Comment: do you need the XML for the content, or only the text content?

Comment: and what do you need to do with the data? store it in a variable, print it, output it to a file, to several files? And yes, XML::Twig can do this in a fairly simple way.

Comment: last question, when you say 'type', do you mean the element name (the tag)?

Comment: Kind of for the content.  What I do with the content depends on the type (element name).  For most types, I will just be saving the content into an array of strings, sometimes doing something special with the string depending on the type.  And for other types, I'm interested in the attribute data, to save into a different array.

Comment: If you've got a specific example, then I'm sure someone'll knock up something suitable in `XML::Twig`. There's two sorts of patterns really - one is load the whole structure as a hash. The other is to use twig handlers to extract just the bits you're interested in (and because you can `purge` you can keep the memory footprint down).

Comment: I'm definitely interested in the whole data.  I just made a very rough pastebin of what the XML may look like - http://pastebin.com/Wb19XX3T

Comment: I switched to [XML::LibXML](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::LibXML) because libxml2 is so widely used and available outside of Perl.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a simple level - `XML::Twig` - traversing children:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings; 

use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new -> parsefile ( 'myxml.xml' );

foreach my $element ( $twig -> root -> children ) { 
    print $element -> text; #element content. 
}
```

Extracting element attributes is either done with:

```
 $element -> att('attributename');
```

Or you can fetch a hash ref with `atts`:

```
 my $attributes = $element -> atts();
 foreach my $key ( keys %$attributes ) {
     print "$key => ", $attributes -> {$key}, "\n";
 }
```

The thing I particularly like though, is that for XML where you've a long list of similar elements, where you're trying to process - you can define a handler - that's called each time the parser encounters and is handed that subset of XML.

```
sub process_book {
     my ( $twig, $book )  = @_;
     print $book -> first_child ('title'); 
     $twig -> purge; #discard anything we've already seen. 
}

my $twig = XML::Twig -> new ( twig_handlers => { 'book' => \&process_book } ); 
$twig -> parsefile ( 'books.xml' );
```

Sample XML:

```
<XML>
   <BOOK>
       <title>Elements of style</title>
       <author>Strunk and White</author>
   </BOOK>
</XML>
```

Comment: This helps me a lot, except I don't see how to figure out when going through each element, how to figure out what the type/name of that element is.  You said `print $element -> text;` ... is there a `print $element -> name;`?  Because what I do with each element, it depends on the element name.. if it's "p" I do one thing, if it's "h3" I do something else, if it's "inline" I do something else, etc, and if it's an unknown element type, it should error out and let me know what the element type/name is so I can figure out how to handle it.

Comment: Update, I just tried `$element -> name` and that worked.

Comment: Text is the content outside the tags. If you're after an attribute, `$element -> att('name');` should do it, generally. (I didn't think `$element -> name` would, but if it does, it does :))

Comment: Yeah... I figured out how to get the attributes from your post, I just couldn't figure out how to find out if it's a "p" tag or a "h3" tag or something else.  The `->name` thing worked for that.

Comment: @DanGodspeed: The `XML::Twig` documentation contains [a section on `XML::Twig::Elt`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig#XML::Twig::Elt) that describes element objects and their methods.  `name`, `tag`, and `gi` (generic identifier) are all aliases for the same method that returns an element's tag name.

Comment: if you do different things depending on the type of the element, then consider using different handlers, one for each element type you process, like (and a `__default__` one for errors), see the 101 section in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

The code below should give you enough information to get started.

A few notes:

- to parse a file use `parsefile` instead of `parse`
- you can also use `'level(1)'` instead of `'/root/*'`
- using a closure to call the handler (`process_elt`), passing `$atts` and `$strings` is the clean way to do this, if you want `$atts` and `$strings` to be global variables you can just write `'/root/*' => \&process_elt` and the handler will be called with the twig and the element as parameters
- the `$t->purge` bit is there to free the memory used by the element you just processed, it is useful if the file is too big to fit in memory, otherwise you don't need to use it
- `DDP` is `Data::Printer`, it's only there to check the output, you can use any other way to do this (`Data::Dumper`, `YAML`, prints...)

Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use XML::Twig;

my $atts    = []; # attributes
my $strings = []; # text content

XML::Twig->new( twig_handlers => 
                 { '/root/*' => sub { process_elt( @_, $strings, $atts); } })
         ->parse( \*DATA);

use DDP; p $atts; p $strings;

sub process_elt
  { my( $t, $elt, $strings, $atts)= @_;

    push @$atts, $elt->atts;

    my $string= $elt->text;
    if( $elt->tag eq 'e1')
      { $string=~ s{text}{modified}; }
    push @$strings, $string;

    $t->purge;
  }

__DATA__
<root>
  <e1 att_1="val_1_1" att2= "val_2_1">text content of element 1</e1>
  <e1 att_1="val_1_2" att2= "val_2_2">text content of element 2</e1>
  <e2 att_3="val_3_1" att2= "val_2_3">element with <sub_elt>sub element</sub_elt> inside</e2>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [XML::LibXML](http://p3rl.org/XML::LibXML). Its `Reader` doesn't need to keep the whole structure in memory, so it can process large files:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

use XML::LibXML::Reader;

my $reader = 'XML::LibXML::Reader'->new( location => 'file.xml' );
while ($reader->read) {
    if (1 == $reader->depth
        and XML_READER_TYPE_ELEMENT == $reader->nodeType
       ) {
        my @info = ($reader->name);
        my $inner = $reader->readInnerXml;
        for my $idx (0 .. $reader->attributeCount - 1) {
            $reader->moveToAttributeNo($idx);
            push @info, $reader->name . '=' . $reader->value;
        }
        push @info, $inner;
        print "@info\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Alas, it looks like XML::LibXML won't install on the server I'm using.

Comment: Is it a Linux server? If so, you can probably install the XML::LibXML module from an OS package (e.g. `apt-get install libxml-libxml-perl` on debian).  For Windows, I believe XML::LibXML is bundled with the popular Perl distributions.

Comment: Oh hey, @GrantMcLean!  I still remember your name fondly from 10 years ago when I decided to shift to XML from tab-delimited text.  I learned a lot from your writing and went all-in with XML because of it.  As far as your question... it's an old Linux server.   Lots of problems with it, things won't install.  I managed for force-install TWIG so that's what I'm working with.  The server is on its way out, I don't even work at the company any more, they just asked me to help get the data out of it for the transition to a new system.